# How to deploy outlook form to other user's folder in his mailbox?

Tags: outlook, outlook-form

I'm a company's exchange administrator.

I've met a problem that if I have a **outlook form** and I can publish it.  But how can I deploy it to **other user's folder in his mailbox**? For example, I can use **EWS  API to create a specific folder** in everyone's mailbox, like "xxx folder". How can I let this folder have this outlook form without people do it **manually**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to deploy a custom form to the Organizational Forms Library. Here is what the [How to determine where to publish a custom Outlook form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290802?wa=wsignin1.0) page states:

> Publish the form to this library if you want to make the form available to everyone in your organization, such as a form to report vacation time. This library is often used for e-mail message forms because they are typically not based on a specific folder. You can publish a form to the Organizational Forms Library when you want to use the same custom form in more than one folder. When you do this, you can maintain only a single published form. Forms that are published to this library are accessible to everyone in the organization as long as they are given permissions to the library by the administrator. The library is stored on the Microsoft Exchange Server-based computer. The administrator must give you permissions to publish to the Organizational Forms Library. This permission is typically given to only a few individuals or a department that manages the Exchange Server-based computer.